# Is this git setup correct?

Tags: git

I have a CMS framework that I use for multiple projects, coded by me. As I do my projects the CMS Gets improved and I often want to use those changes in subsequent projects.
Often I have multiple projects on the go at once however.

After reading up on git I know I could branch off each project and commit CMS improvements back to the master and then redistribute to other branches but that seems wrong. Especially in a years time when some projects are finished but the core CMS is looking very different to how it was when they used it. It would also mean switching between branches when switching between projects. Also would every machine i used it on get a copy of every branch ever when i created the repo on that machine?

The other option seems to be cloning. I have a main repo that contains the 'core' CMS, each project becomes a clone of this and is worked on separately. This seems more intuitive, but can I merge back some changes in the clone to the core, and can I distribute core changes to the other clones?

EDIT:
Thinking about it more, cloning is the term i think for copying a repo onto a machine (of which i use several, that i would want to keep up to date with the latest version of some of the projects). So maybe i should be 'forking'? is that just a github thing though?

Does either option seem the correct method? All advice appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The other option seems to be cloning. I have a main repo that contains
>   the 'core' CMS, each project becomes a clone of this and is worked on
>   separately. This seems more intuitive, but can I merge back some
>   changes in the clone to the core, and can I distribute core changes to
>   the other clones?

For anyone else that comes across this - cloning was the way to go here.
It allows you to have all the sites as separate folders on your computer, so you can switch easily without checking out branches etc. 
It then allows you to push changes from each clone onto the production server and/or back to the core repository (origin). Then from origin you can push changes out onto whichever other instances you like.
Nifty use of `.gitignore`, `--assume-unchanged` and adjusting each project to have a "theme" folder meant that you can push all changes around without worrying too much about one sites individuality overwriting another.

Answer (score 0):

I actually faced a similar problem. So what I did is creating 2 repositories. One with the core of the application that every instances has to have in order to work.

On top of of that a repository for each instance's specific files and configs.

The core-repo was tagged with version numbers where every tag on the master of the core was a working version.

That allows to check out a specific tag and keep individual data in the instance repos. What you cannot do with this setup is keepong specific code in instance repos and merge intohe other instances. You could do that if you either hace just 1 instance repo and you branch each instance in there or you could use something lile composer (www.getcomposer.org) to keep your dependencies in line.

Comment: thanks, its an interesting idea but i found a way that works for me.